# How to determine which libc implementation the host system uses

Tags: python, linux, glibc, musl

In our Python setup code that uses pre-built binaries and a bindings generator, we check the operating system and CPU architecture, and download binaries accordingly.

Now, there are binaries for both manylinux (glibc) and musllinux (musl). How can we find out which libc implementation the host system uses?
I am aware of `platform.libc_ver()`, but for musl hosts, it currently just returns two empty strings (see [CPython issue 87414](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/87414)).

However, there has to be more precise code available already, as `pip` needs means to choose the right wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I am using now. It is insipred by @AndrewNelson's answer and also uses the platform module, but it is written as an overlay for `platform.libc_ver()` and calls into `packaging._musllinux` directly.

```py
import sys
import platform
import packaging._musllinux

def get_libc_info():
    name, ver = platform.libc_ver()
    if not name:
        musl_ver = packaging._musllinux._get_musl_version(sys.executable)
        if musl_ver:
            name, ver = "musl", f"{musl_ver.major}.{musl_ver.minor}"
    return name, ver

print( get_libc_info() )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from packaging.tags import sys_tags
tags = list(sys_tags())
print('musllinux' in tags[0].platform)
```

Comment: Interesting. I guess I should take a closer look at packaging. While this doesn't look like the optimal API, I'll want to read packaging's `_musllinux.py` file. I still think a more optimal solution would be if packaging's musl detection code could be moved into the standard library, though.

Comment: If you are building wheels, you can use something like `from wheel.vendored.packaging.tags import platform_tags # or sys_tags`. The package `pip` also have this stuff, but `pip` may not exist.

Comment: Coming back to this, there is actually an open CPython PR now https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/103784

Answer (score -1):

If you are just checking for glibc vs musl, why not just:

```
import platform

def is_musl():
    libc, version = platform.libc_ver()
    return libc != "glibc"
```

Comment: that's actually what I'm doing ATM, but it's somewhat unsafe as further libc implementations other than glibc and musl may exist on linux, though uncommon